# Метод post в ссылках

Tags: php, javascript, html

Хочу сделать единую форму , без указания action 
И вывести ниже две ссылки, редактировать и удалить, у редактировать action="edit.php" у удалить action="delete.php", как мне это сделать?

Comment: Очень невнятный вопрос, но я прозреваю, что вам нужен `<input type='hidden' name='id' />`

Comment: Мне нужно в зависимости от нажатия на ссылку, проставлялось значение в action="вот сюда"

Comment: На джава скрипте, конечно же. Советую вобще отправлять формы с помощью AJAX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой подход не в моем вкусе но это именно то что вы просили.

Вот часть `html` разметки:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">

    //inputes
    <input type="text" name="text" value="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
</form>
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type=submit]').on('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().attr('action',$(this).attr('name')+'.php');
        });
    });
    
</script>
```

Второй вариант без `javascript`:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">

    //inputes
    <input type="text" name="text" value="text" />
    <button name="edit" value="edit" formaction="edit.php">edit</button>
    <button name="delete" value="delete" formaction="delete.php" onClick="return confirm('Want to delete?');">delete</button>
</form>
```

Подробно о [formaction](http://htmlbook.ru/html/button/formaction)

Comment: а можно без подключения edit и delete? У меня просто эти файлы находятся отдельно от основной формы, единственное что объединяет эти все файлы, это id,который как раз передается в основной форме

Comment: @Never3D Дайте подробный пример вашего кода в вопросе.

Comment: http://www.note-pad.net/ru/secretlink/1f66fadf9c3bfaac3c9040952d256d24?page=1

Comment: Просто сделать так хочу <form action="edit.php,delete.php" method="POST"> вот при нажатии, ссылки снизу или кнопки было, либо edit либо delete

Comment: @Never3D Изменил ответ.

Comment: Не работает, но в любом случае я сделал, оказалось еще проще) Но возник вопрос, как при нажатии на кнопку delete, был alert с надписью "Вы уверены что хотите удалить?". И кнопочки, если Да, но просто перейти на страницу delete.php, если нет, то просто оставить на текущей

Comment: @Never3D Я с ново проверил и оно работает нормально, каждый раз `action` разный в зависимости на что нажимаешь.

Comment: Ок, но я сделал formaction, Но возник вопрос, как при нажатии на кнопку delete, был alert с надписью "Вы уверены что хотите удалить?". И кнопочки, если Да, но просто перейти на страницу delete.php, если нет, то просто оставить на текущей

Comment: @Never3D Обновил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Сделал методом. Но возник вопрос, как при нажатии на кнопку delete, был alert с надписью "Вы уверены что хотите удалить?"

```
&nbsp;<input class="btn btn-gold" type="submit" name="edit" value="Изменить" formaction="edit.php">
&nbsp;<input class="btn btn-red" type="submit" name="delete" value="Удалить" formaction="delete.php">
```